# Запуск subprocess от имени питона, расположенного в virtualenv

Tags: python, flask

Здравствуйте. Пишу на python 3.4 и flask свой небольшой сервис с инженерными расчетами. Понадобилось применение стороннего приложения GMSH, запуск которого происходит через pygmsh через subprocess.

```
    cmd = [gmsh_executable, '-3', filename, '-o', outname]
    if optimize:
        cmd += ['-optimize']
    out = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Учитывая, что веб-сервер работает через пользователя www-data из виртуального окружения, получаю ошибку "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied", когда subprocess вызывает python 3.4 из глобального окружения, доступного только для root.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно запустить подпроцесс через виртуальное окружение, без выхода в root? С python пока на Вы, к сожалению.

Comment: покажите полный traceback. Что такое `gmsh_executable`? (если это Питон-скрипт, то покажите его первую строчку (shebang `#!`) Что значит "глобальное окружение"? Чем оно отличается от не глобального окружения?

Comment: Все зависит от того, можно ли в gmsh передать прямо путь до питона. Посмотрите, что в sys.executable под virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в переменную окружения PATH путь до Питона в virtualenv. Что-нибудь вроде такого:

```
import os

env = os.environ.copy()
if 'PATH' in env:
    env['PATH'] = 'Путь до virtualenv/bin:' + env['PATH']
else:
    env['PATH'] = 'Путь до virtualenv/bin:'

cmd = [gmsh_executable, '-3', filename, '-o', outname]
if optimize:
    cmd += ['-optimize']
out = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=env)
```

Возможно, подобным образом нужно будет изменить еще переменные окружения PYTHONPATH и PYTHONHOME.